# Query function problem

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

When using a query function that selects two columns from another sheet, I get two results in one cell. It looks like it doesn't respect the initial structure of the selected data. Any idea, please?

[image]

Comment: your column C is formatted for numbers and also for text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TO_TEXT(A1:C6)), "select Col1, Col2 where Col3 !='0'")
```

[image]

Comment: From review: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its **length** and **content**.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FILTER(A1:C7,C1:C7<>0),9999,2)
```

[image]

Comment: From review: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its **length and content**.